# Using `Omit` for types in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am developing node.js project with Typescript.

I would like to omit 3 properties of a type, I know I could do:

```
 const newType = Omit<OringalType, 'property1' | 'property2' | 'property3'>
```

But I would like to extract out those properties to a const variable and use the variable for concise code on each line:

```
// ERROR: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type
const omitProps = 'property1' | 'property2' | 'property3';

const newType = Omit<OringalType, omitProps>
```

As you can see, I get compiler error.  What is the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: `const omitProps` -> `type omitProps`

Comment: And `const newType = ...` => `type newType = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Types and values exist in different universes when it comes to TypeScript, you have to be careful not to mix the two.

It seems to me that you are trying to operate at the type level, so you'd probably want to do something like this.

```js
type OriginalType = {
    property1: 1
    property2: 2
    property3: 3
    property4: 4
}
type NewType = Omit<OriginalType, 'property1' | 'property2' | 'property3'> 

const n1: NewType = { property4: 4 }
const n2: NewType ={ property1: 1, property4: 4 } // err
```